# Windows 7 Enterprise - double-click on .bat file doesn't work - Windows can't find the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, double-click

When I double click on a file .bat it throws error:  "Windows can't find file .bat." If I use cmd or right-click and run as administrator it works. On collegue's computer the double-click works. I verified I have the same registry settings like my collegues. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, if `run as administrator` works, may be that in `enterprise` versions users of S-1-5-32-544 group except the built-in Administrator account have the `Elevated admin=No` as, by default, the `User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode` directive is enabled.

So, try changing it either with secpol.msc or setting EnableLUA=0 in the registry.

Using secpol.msc under

1. local security policy
2. local policies
3. security options
4. User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode=disable

or using registry under

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
2. EnableLUA=0

Comment: i verify User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode=disable, it like that i change nothing

Answer (score 0):

A .BAT file is just a text file with a list of instructions.

Open the .BAT file in Notepad.

Look at each line of the .BAT file to see what file does not exist on your PC.

If you do not understand the .BAT file, edit your post to include the file's contents.

Comment: I found why, because i have a wrong thing in variable environnement, in variable system named ComSpec a path of maven which should never be here